# Lines not executed in the good order while dying in foreach loop

Tags: perl, foreach, die

I just have a strange behavior I would like to understand.

Here is my perl script, where I just check if some folders are present :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;

$root = "C:\\Data\\Tests";
@check = ("folder1", "folder2", "folder3");
foreach $check (@check){
    print $check;
    print -d "$root\\$check" ? " OK\n" : die " NOK : not accessible";
}
```

Now, assume that folder3 is missing, so I should have the output:

```
folder1 OK
folder2 OK
folder3 NOK : not accessible at C:\Data\Tests\strange.pl line 8.
```

Instead I have :

```
folder1 OK
folder2 OK
 NOK : not accessible at C:\Data\Tests\strange.pl line 8.
folder3
```

So it looks like in the last loop, the second line is executed before the first..

Someone knows why ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So it looks like in the last loop, the second line is executed before the first..
>
> Someone knows why ?

`die ".."` unlike `print` goes to `STDERR`

Furthermore output is buffered so you might want to disable it in order to get wanted output,

```
STDOUT->autoflush();
STDERR->autoflush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one print statement, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;

$root = "C:\\Data\\Tests";
@check = ("folder1", "folder2", "folder3");
foreach $check (@check){
    print -d "$root\\$check" ? "$check OK\n" : die "$check NOK : not accessible";
}
```

Comment: Yes it works this way, but doesn't explain the streange behavior I'm experiencing :)